# Swift: Setting label text in the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, null, label, appdelegate

I have a view controller containing two labels. I want to set the value of those labels from the AppDelegate. I get a crash and when I debug it, I found that the labels are nil.
This is how I call the view controller in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
     self.homeViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeViewController") as! HomeViewController
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkForReachability), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)}
```

And inside the `checkForReachability` I set the labels text. For example:

```
self.homeViewController.labelNetworkType.text = "WIFI";
```

I already verified that the labels are connected to the view controller. 
How can I solve that? Have I this problem because my app is a single view application and I recall the main view in the AppDelegate?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your homeViewController add something like this.

```
var networkTypeText: String = "Default value" {
    didSet {
        if let networkType = labelNetworkType {
            networkType.text = networkTypeText
        }
    }
}
```

and in viewDidLoad do it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labelNetworkType!.text = networkTypeText
}
```

If you go this way, first time when you load your view controller it will have default value. Each time when you trigger set of networkTypeText value it will automatically update label if the label is not nil. Beside this, if you set value for networkTypeText in app delegate before initiating outlet, it will be set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: After testing your code, the label are not nil but it's always the default value that is shown

Answer (score 3):

change the type of your label Outlet from `UILabel!` to `UILabel?`

Until your controller is presented, the outlet are not created. So the `UILabel!` will produce  `optional unwrapping value failed`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In addition to your suggestion I have also added `?` in the labels :  `self.homeViewController.labelNetworkType?.text = "WIFI" ` and it works. But I got another problem: the label doesn't get the new text. It has the value that I set in the storyboard. Am I missing another think?

Comment: When you set the text, the view controller doesn't exist yet. You should call `checkForReachability` in the `viewDidLoad` method to get the correct value on first display

Comment: How can I do that? Because I call it in the AppDelegate file

Comment: Store the last result in an attribute of your AppDelegate, and fetch this value in the giewdidlaod method

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to change the view controller outlet value before they appear, instead, make a variable to store it, and set it in your outlet's `didSet` or `viewDidLoad`

In your `homeViewController`:

```
var networkTypeText = "" {
   didSet {
      labelNetworkType.text = networkTypeText
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Thank you but I tested it and the problem is always here. Can you please take a look on my comment in @bobby 's answer?

Comment: Did you tried to put break point in the `didSet ` code and see if it got called after the code in `checkForReachability `?

Comment: The `networkTypeText` has  the value that I have set in the AppDelegate "WIFI" but the label is not set

Comment: Yes it got called but the label is nil and the `networkTypeText` has "WIFI"

Comment: Try call `labelNetworkType.text = networkTypeText` in `viewWillAppear` also, I think the `networkTypeText` got assigned value before your view appear that's why your label is nil

Comment: I tried what you tell me to do but the label still having the default value